# Updating user via UserManager clears navigation property

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a user class with a navigation property that acts as the join model for a many-to-many relationship.

As an example:

```
class User
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public ICollection<UserFoo> Foos { get; set; }
}

class UserFoo
{
    public string UserId { get; set; }

    public User User { get; set; }

    public int FooId { get; set; }

    public Foo Foo { get; set; }
}

class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public ICollection <UserFoo> Users { get; set; }
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    builder.Entity<UserFoo>
        .HasOne(uf => uf.User)
        .WithMany(u => u.Foos)
        .HasForeignKey(uf => uf.UserId);

    builder.Entity<UserFoo>
        .HasOne(uf => uf.Foo)
        .WithMany(u => u.Users)
        .HasForeignKey(uf => uf.FooId);
}
```

When updating a user with the `UserManager` class, it exhibits strange behaviour with the navigation property.

The first time I add some relationships to the user, it updates fine as you would expect.

Any subsequent time I make changes, that's when things get weird.
If a user has a link to FooA and FooB, adding a link to FooC will erase FooA and FooB, resulting in only FooC.
If a user has a link to FooA and FooB, removing either of them removes all links.

The weird state comes after calling `UserManager.UpdateAsync` - the user model passed to it is in the correct state before the call, and the wrong one after the call ends.

I've traced this down to the internal call to `Store.UpdateAsync`. I can't figure out where to go from there, other than switching to using a context to update the user.

The update method (snipped):

```
public IActionResult Update(string id, UserForm form)
{
    // form in correct state

    var user = userManager.Users.Include(u => u.Foos).FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == id);
    // user in correct state

    var role = await roleManager.FindByIdAsync(form.RoleId);
    mapper.Map(form, user); // AutoMapper
    // user now in correct state after mapping

    var result = await userManager.UpdateAsync(user, role, form.Password);
    // user in incorrect state
}
```

Comment: can you show your update method?

Comment: Sounds like there's an issue with the change tracking, which is normally caused by incorrectly accepting an entity directly from a post and saving it directly to the database. We need to see your action that handles the update, but more likely than not, you can solve the issue simply by using a view model class and mapping to an entity pulled fresh from the database.

Comment: Updated the OP to include a sample of the update code. I suspect the entity returned by the `UserManager` does not have change tracking.

Comment: check again your mapping if there any mismatch property then
 just use this line of code for update..............
 var result = await userManager.UpdateAsync(user);